# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar datos almacenados en LocalStorage al presionar un boton con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, python, flask

Alguien que pueda apoyarme en como puedo eliminar datos almacenados en el LocalStorage al precionar un boton en javaScript?. Lo que estoy realizando es que primero se almacene los datos de un formulario en LocalStorage y después al presionar un boton se borren esos datos que está almacenado.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#nombre, #apellido_P, #apellido_M, #email, #telefono').each(function(){    
      var name = $(this).attr('name'); 
      value=localStorage.getItem(name);
      var value = $(this).val(value);
     })

    setInterval(function(){
    $('#nombre, #apellido_P, #apellido_M, #email, #telefono').each(function(){    
      var name = $(this).attr('name');
      var value = $(this).val();
      localStorage.setItem(name, value);
    })
  

 }, 1000);
```

})

Ese es como almaceno en LocalStorage, ahora quiero eliminar pero al precionar un boton. Graciass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No creo que requiera de una explicacion muy compleja, simplemente añadele el evento a tu boton y dentro del cuerpo remueve el item que te interese:

```
$("#idDeTuBoton").on("click", ()=>{
     localStorage.removeItem(name);
});
```

Comment: Apenas ví tu respuesta hermano, voy y te cuento que tal marcha. Saludos